# SQL Server Service Broker using DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, sqlclr, service-broker

I am converting a console application to run from [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) in SQL Server 2005.

The application makes heavy use of [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset_members(VS.80).aspx).

Are DataSets supposed to work in [SQLCLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s0s2at1(VS.80).aspx)? How do I define the connection to use? Is there any documentation about this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean run FROM service broker? SB is in essence a message queuing system.

Comment: He probably means Activation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit generic, but I hope this helps you:
DataSet is contained in the assembly [System.data.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data(VS.80).aspx) which is one of the [approved assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx) for the SQLCLR. So, yes, you can use DataSets.